# $\ker (I-A)=\{0\}\Rightarrow\text{im }(I-A)=H$ for $A:H\to H$ compact

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $T$ be the operator defined by $T:=I-A$ where $I:H\to H$ is the identity and $A:H\to H$ is a compact operator defined on Hilbert space $H$. In such a case, if we defined the chain of sets$$H\supset H^1\supset H^2\supset\ldots\supset H^k\supset \ldots$$by $H^k:=T(H^{k-1})$, there must be a $j\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall k\ge j\quad H^{k+1}=H^k$ (p. 470 [here](http://inis.jinr.ru/sl/vol2/Mathematics/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2,%D0%A4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD,_%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B8_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0,1976.pdf)).

In order to prove that $\ker T=\{0\}\Rightarrow \text{im }H=H$ (where $\text{im }H:=T(H)$), Kolmogorov and Fomin ([p. 470](http://inis.jinr.ru/sl/vol2/Mathematics/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2,%D0%A4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD,_%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B8_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0,1976.pdf)) say that *if $\ker T=\{0\}$ then operator $T$ will be injective and, consequentially, if $\text{im }H\ne H$, the sequence $H\supset H^1\supset H^2\supset\ldots$ will be composed of distinct subspaces, which contradicts* the fact that $\exists j\in\mathbb{N}:$ $\forall k\ge j\quad H^{k+1}=H^k$.

Why, if $T$ is injective, must all $H^k$ be distinct? I see that $H^1\subsetneq H$, but I do not see why they are all distinct. I know that $H=\ker T\oplus\text{im }T^\ast$, but adjoint operator $T^\ast$ does not seem to be used here, to me, and I am not sure whether it is useful to understand this implication.
Thank you so much for any explanation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the $H^k$ are descending, having $H^m = H^n$ for some $n > m$ means $H^k = H^m$ for all $k \geqslant m$, as $H^m \supset H^{m+1} \supset \dotsc \supset H^n = H^m$ forces all these spaces to be equal, and then, for $k \geqslant m$ we have $H^{k+2} = T(H^{k+1}) = T(H^k) = H^{k+1}$ by induction.

Suppose that $H^1\subsetneq H$, but the $H^k$ are not all distinct. Then the sequence $(H^k)$ stabilizes at some point, say

$$H^{m-1} \supsetneq H^m = H^{m+1}.$$

Then look at some $x\in H^{m-1}\setminus H^m$. We have $Tx\in H^m$ by definition, and hence $Tx \in H^{m+1}$ by assumption. But that means there is an $y\in H^m$ with $Tx = Ty$. Then $x-y \in \ker T$, but by construction $y-x \in H^{m-1}\setminus H^m$, so $y-x \neq 0$, hence $\ker T \neq \{0\}$.

Thus, if the sequence stabilizes at some point, but is not constant from the beginning, then $T$ cannot be injective. By contrapositive, if $T$ is injective, either $H^1 = H$ or $H^{k+1} \subsetneq H^k$ for all $k$.

Comment: Just one doubt: why $y-x\in H^{m-1}\setminus H^m$ by construction? Thank you very very much!!!

Comment: Because we picked $x\in H^{m-1}\setminus H^m$, and $y\in H^m$, so their difference lies in $H^{m-1}$, since both belong to that, but not in $H^m$, since only one of the two belongs to $H^m$. (And don't ask me why I switched from $x-y$ to $y-x$. That was an accident. Fortunately it doesn't make anything invalid.)

Comment: Wonderfully clear! I heartily thank you!